# How do i get the date from week of month and day of week with Carbon?

Tags: php-carbon

I have a date, I want to get from week of month and day of week of any month.

Example:

- Date: 2021-04-26 (Monday)
- Week of month: 5
- Day of week: 1

I want to get the date of May by week of month and day of week.
The date I want to get is "2021-05-24"

How can I do that with Carbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$month = 5;
$weekOfMonth = 5;
$dayOfWeek = 1;

echo Carbon::parse("2021-$month-1")
    ->startOfWeek()
    ->addWeeks($weekOfMonth - 1)
    ->addDays($dayOfWeek - 1);
```

Comment: Glad to hear, please mark this answer as the solution for next users searching this. Thanks.